# Timestamp of zombies

Tags: cassandra, datastax

If a deleted record comes back in cassandra, will the record have the original timestamp or new timestamp?

E.g. a value gets inserted on Apr-2016. It was deleted on Jun-2016. But due to gc_grace/no repairs etc., the value came back on Jul-2016. Will the timestamp of the zombie be Apr-2016 or Jul-2016?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apr-2016.

If a tombstone is purged then an anti-entropy task (either read repair or operational) restores the original cell from another node that never received the tombstone, it will still have the original timestamp. Timestamps on cells are not updated when received.